# c# object oriented programming foundamentals

Tags: c#, oop, class, object

I'm new of the Object Oriented Programming methods:

I have a class MyClass1 as follow:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

There is also a class MyClass2 defined as:

```
public class Myclass2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Myclass2(MyClass1 m) { }

}
```

MyClass2 exists only if exists MyClass1, because in MyClass2 I need some properties of the MyClass1.

The best for me will be some like this:

```
MyClass1.MyClass2 = new MyClass2();
```

Ofcourse the constructor of MyClass2 should take MyClass1.

What is the best method to achieve this using C# Object Oriented Programming ?

Comment: `public class Myclass2 : MyClass1 {....`

Comment: Look at using inheritance in c# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I think this wants the homework tag, and some clarification, before we see a flood of upvotes.

Comment: based on your example its best to delete `MyClass2`, it adds nothing. How would `MyClass2` be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like MyClass2 should inherit from MyClass1, but you've not really explained what you are trying to accomplish well enough to be sure that's what you want.

Comment: agreed:  inner class might be a better option for OP depending on usage

Answer (score 4):

[Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public class Myclass2 : Myclass1
{
    public Myclass2() { }
}
```

You may also want to look at [Nested types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public class Myclass2
{
    public class Myclass1
    { 
        Myclass1(){}
    }
}
```